# How can I style a volume (ramp) like slider in javafx via css?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have limited but basic understanding of how a slider can be styled via css in java FX. I have defined the -fx-shape of the .slider .track class in the form I want it to be in (triangle). How can I style the .bar such that it “fills” the triangle from left(min) to right(max)?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [css reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)? It describes every class and attribute available with the JavaFX Slider.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your question and show a part of your data. Have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for !